# What does "<" isolate binding mean

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've recently come across the following "<" isolate binding in the source code:

```
switch (mode) {

case '@':
...
case '=':
...
case '&':
...

case '<':
    if (!hasOwnProperty.call(attrs, attrName)) {
      if (optional) break;
      attrs[attrName] = void 0;
    }
    if (optional && !attrs[attrName]) break;

    parentGet = $parse(attrs[attrName]);

    destination[scopeName] = parentGet(scope);
    initialChanges[scopeName] = new SimpleChange(_UNINITIALIZED_VALUE, destination[scopeName]);

    removeWatch = scope.$watch(parentGet, function parentValueWatchAction(newValue, oldValue) {
      if (newValue === oldValue) {
        // If the new and old values are identical then this is the first time the watch has been triggered
        // So instead we use the current value on the destination as the old value
        oldValue = destination[scopeName];
      }
      recordChanges(scopeName, newValue, oldValue);
      destination[scopeName] = newValue;
    }, parentGet.literal);

    removeWatchCollection.push(removeWatch);
    break;
```

Angular docs mention only the first three, what is the purpose of this one "<"?

Comment: From component [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component): `The < symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5.`.

Comment: ah, thanks a lot, this is a new feature then, I got to read about that.

Comment: Check this nice post: https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/

Comment: cool, very much obliged, best!